# Bash - for each line sum the numbers occurring in the columns indicated [by argument]

Tags: bash

The script sum together the appropriate column (that is, each line sum the numbers occurring in the columns indicated), creates the resulting column of numbers and writes it to stdout. In the absence of argument "column" is assumed by default column number 1.

Usage: ./script.sh filename [column1 ...]

That's what I've got to sum num for each line.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  echo "Usage: ./script.sh filename [column1 column2 ...]"
fi

filename=$1
shift

while read line
do
  sum=0
  for num in $line
  do
    let sum=sum+num
  done
  echo "Sum: " $sum
done < $filename
```

How to sum the numbers occurring in the columns indicated by argument [column1 column2 ....] for each line and creates the resulting column of numbers and writes it to stdout. Please give me some ideas what tool should be used to solve the issue.

Comment: *Please give me some ideas what tool should be used to solve the issue.* **awk**

Comment: `awk` is good. Without `awk` you can use some tool (`cut`or `sed`) to extract the colums first. When you do not want to loop through the remaining values adding each field with `(( sum += i ))`, you can concatenate everything to one line (`tr '\n' ' '`) and use `tr`again for replacing spaces by '+'. Now you have a string that you can `|` to `bc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by expanding your existing script, something like this should work (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ];then
  echo "Usage: ./script.sh filename [column1 column2 ...]" &&  exit 1 
  #exit the script - no further processing
fi

[ ! -f $1 ] && echo "Filename given not a valid file-exiting" && exit 1

filename=$1 && shift 

while [ $# -ge 1 ];do    #Read all args and put them in an array
  toadd+=( "$1" ) && shift
done

while read -r line;do           #Read line from file
  read -ra columns <<<"$line"   #split the line into field using an array
  sum=0
  for i in "${toadd[@]}";do     #For items in array $toadd
    num="${columns[$i-1]}"      #get the corresponding element from array columns
    let sum=sum+num
  done

  echo "Sum: " $sum
done < $filename
exit 0
```

PS: This works for space delimited records of files (col1 col2 ....)

Comment: Thanks. @George_Vasiliou your solution helped